# How to add morocco Country code to phone numbers in wp woocomerce after checkout?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to add country code to the woocomerce output.

I Have a small issue, In My Country, We start writing Numbers With zero (0) but I need the number to be written without a 0 and with morocco country code.

for example if someone wright it like 0600290157 it becomes in the backend only like that: 212600290107

Other case if +212600290107 ---> 212600290107
Other case if 00212600290107 ---> 212600290107

So I need the number to look like 212xxxxxxxxx

I need a code to add it to my Wordpress woocommerce website in fonction.php

Best Regards

Comment: Create a new field in your checkout. Make it required where they should type the county code or make it dropdown and list all codes. Then on completing order merge both fields. Another option is using regex to check if number starts with + or 00 . Second option is more if you sell only localy in your country so you can say hey i need 10 digits. 3rd option is if customer select county based on that country to merge to the phone number county code. But what happen if customer actualy enter phone number properly ?

Comment: Check this plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/country-code-selector/ or this one - https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-international-phone-input/7960098

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite code country after complete typing number like this:
This is work only for morocco numbers 06 or 07

```js
    document.querySelector('input[name="phone_number"]').addEventListener('keyup',function(e){
        let value = this.value;
        if (value.length == 10 && ['06','07'].includes(value.slice(0, 2))) {
            this.value = '+212'+ value.slice(1);
        }
    });
```

```html
<input type="text" name="phone_number">
```

The second solution is make another input to fix the code country
try it:

```js
    let ph_input = document.querySelector('input[name="phone_number"]');
    //ph_input.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    let clone = ph_input.cloneNode(true);
    ph_input.parentElement.appendChild(clone).setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    let name = ph_input.getAttribute('name') + '_fix_code';
    ph_input.setAttribute('default_name', ph_input.getAttribute('name'));
    ph_input.setAttribute('name', name);


    document.querySelector(`input[name="${name}"]`).addEventListener('keyup',function(e){
        let value = this.value;
        let name = this.getAttribute('default_name');
        let default_input = document.querySelector(`input[name="${name}"]`);
        default_input.value = value;
        if (value.length == 10 && ['06','07'].includes(value.slice(0, 2))) {
            default_input.value = '+212'+ value.slice(1);
        }
    });


    // Button For Test
    document.querySelector(`.test`).addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        let value = document.querySelector('input[name="phone_number"]').value;
        alert(value);
    });
```

```html
<input type="text" name="phone_number">
<button class="test">Test</button>
```

To add the code into wordpress go to your active theme edit file functions.php and put this code at the end of the functions.php

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'fix_code_country');
function fix_code_country()
{
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        try {
            let ph_input = document.querySelector('input[name="phone_number"]');
            //ph_input.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
            let clone = ph_input.cloneNode(true);
            ph_input.parentElement.appendChild(clone).setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
            let name = ph_input.getAttribute('name') + '_fix_code';
            ph_input.setAttribute('default_name', ph_input.getAttribute('name'));
            ph_input.setAttribute('name', name);

            document.querySelector(`input[name="${name}"]`).addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
                let value = this.value;
                let name = this.getAttribute('default_name');
                let default_input = document.querySelector(`input[name="${name}"]`);
                default_input.value = value;
                if (value.length == 10 && ['06', '07'].includes(value.slice(0, 2))) {
                    default_input.value = '+212' + value.slice(1);
                }
            });
        } catch {}
    </script>
<?php
};
```

or you can install plugin to insert the code in footer
check this documentation: https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/add-code-wordpress-header-footer/

Comment: hello M younes bennour. thanks for the answer, please let me know how I can add the second code as a filtre to Wordpress woocomerce code to get results in the backend on woocomerce commands.

Comment: Check the update, I provide two possibilities, you can choose the right for you

Comment: thanks  so much M younes bennour